# Translate IP address at router

Tags: networking, routing, cisco

I'm not sure if this is possible, and if it is possible surely it is frowned upon but... is it possible to perform dynamic translation of an IP address on a Cisco 3650 L3 router?

Here is the scenario:

- Multiple clients exist on subnets 10.0.1.0/24 to 10.0.100.0/24.
- Clients transmit data to server 10.101.0.1/24.
- The server's IP address will change to 10.201.0.1/24.
- The clients must continue to transfer data to the server, but the server IP setting cannot be changed on the client (i.e. clients will continue to send data to 10.101.0.1/24).
- Routing between these three networks is carried out by a Cisco 3650 L3 router.
- The clients do not have DNS configured.
- Basically, the client settings cannot change.

I am thinking that maybe there is some funky layer three magic could happen at the Cisco switch that would allow for dynamic translation between 10.101.0.1 and 10.201.0.1 so that clients would be able to continue to send data to the server without modifying any client settings.

Is this scenario possible? If it is, what specific Cisco configuration would be needed, and what strange drawbacks/ramifications could be expected?

Comment: A possible alternative may be to have a reverse proxy in TCP mode listening on the old server’s address. The drawback is if the new server needs to know the origin IP addresses for some reason: that may be hard to replicate.

Comment: @MikaelH Thank you for the comment. I do not think that the server will need to know anything about the client. Interesting idea.

Comment: NAT is supported on routers and firewalls, NOT on CISCO switches (generally speaking) so that's excluded. A solution would be the target NIC to have both IPs configured, one to be used for client connect and the other for the new purpose it was put like that for.

Comment: @Overmind Thank you for your comment. The new and old server IP's will be associated with different subnets on different switch ports, and there will be other servers that remain on the old subnet that will keep their old IPs so I don't think that will work.

Comment: It's not a problem if they are on different sub-nets; if you need to use different switch ports you will need 2 NICs. Everything should be fine as long as you figure out what proper routing you need and set some metrics accordingly.

Comment: @Overmind are you suggesting adding another NIC to the server such that one NIC connected to the old subnet and the other NIC to the new subnet? That's a nice idea, but unfortunately the new subnet will be in the cloud so I don't think that there will be a way to connect the server directly to the old subnet.

Comment: That really depends on how much control you have in that could. You should definitely be able to add a new virtual NIC interface, but reaching back correctly to the initial infrastructure may not be possible.